# Multicol on large format document

Tags: formatting

I'm trying to create a poster-sized document (24"x36", 27"x40") with code listing across 10-15 columns. I've tried `multicols` and `multicols*` environments, but both end up failing once an extend gets too large in one direction or the other - `multicols` fails when columns need to exceed around 18" in height, and `multicols*` fails when the number of columns filled exceeds around 14" in width.

The failure mode is to fill up the first page and spill to a second (or multiple) pages and all but the last page will fail in the same way - typically the last page doesn't fail because the content is small enough to fit within the above constraints.

Here is an example with `multicols*` failing:

[image: multicols* what's wrong with you!?]

Here's an example with `multicols` failing:

[image: multicols what's wrong with you?!]

If I can stay within these mystery constraints, say by reducing the font size, the layout is satisfactory. I just want to be able to fill more of the page.

[image]

Are these dimensions too large for `multicols`?

UPDATE: Thanks for the early help in the comments. Here is a minimal document that contains the issue:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{fp}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\geometry{paperwidth=24in,paperheight=36in,margin=2cm}

\usepackage{multicol}

% make a label command
\newcommand{\lbl}[1]{\tikz[remember picture,inner sep=0pt] \node(#1) {};}%
\newcommand{\addr}[1]{\lbl{ADDR_#1}}%
\newcommand{\data}[1]{\texttt{#1}}%
\newcommand{\op}[1]{\texttt{#1}}%

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{multicols}{13}

{\ttfamily\fontsize{4.5}{5}\selectfont\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

% new block
{\hspace*{-2em}DATA\_00000107:}\\
{\hspace*{-2em}CATCH\_00000200:}\\
\addr{0x200}nop\\
bra.b \#-\$4\lbl{JMP_0x202}\\

% new block
{\hspace*{-2em}TRAP\_0000020c:}\\
\addr{0x20c}rte\\
{\hspace*{-2em}MAIN:}\\
\addr{0x20e}tst.l (\#\$a10008).l\\
bne.b \#\$6\lbl{JMP_0x214}\\
tst.w (\#\$a1000c).l\\
{\hspace*{-2em}LABEL\_0000021c:}\\
\addr{0x21c}bne.b \#\$7c\lbl{JMP_0x21c}\\
lea (\#\$7c, PC), A5\\

% a real listing has >10k additional lines

}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

And as @ulrike-fischer pointed out, I do get `Dimension too large.` errors:

```
! Dimension too large.
\set@mult@vsize ...dima \vsize \col@number \vsize 
                                                  \advance \vsize -\@tempdim...

l.20 
   
? r
OK, entering \nonstopmode...

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 23--26


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 27--36

! Dimension too large.
\endmulticols ...@botmark }\else \ifdim \pagegoal 
                                                  =\maxdimen \ifvoid \colbre...

l.40 \end{multicols}
                  
[1{/opt/local/var/db/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./sample-listing.aux))
```

As @david-carlisle suggested, I did reduce the size of the document and scaled everything appropriately and I can now generate a PDF without errors. I think this will allow me to get by for now. It's odd working with such small dimensions, but ultimately the output seems scaled correctly.

[image]

If I'm following how `multicol` works, the text is rendered as if it were all in a single column first, which at 36" high reaches `\maxdimen` somewhere in the 7ᵀᴴ column. I hadn't thought about the "how". Does `multicol*` need to do this calculation as well? I suppose it needs the full dimension to find where column breaks will ultimately appear to avoid a ragged bottom on the "full" columns?

Is there a technical constraint for `\maxdimen`'s value or way to configure to something higher?

Thanks again. This is definitely getting me closer to what I'd like the final output to look like.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!. You need to provide more information about what you doing in form of small but complete document which  produce showed image.

Comment: don't you get errors? If your columns have a height of 36in ~ 91cm, then you will exceed `\maxdimen` with seven columns and should get a `! Dimension too large.` error.

Comment: if you get _any_ error you should ask about the error message not show pdfoutput (which is never intended to be usable after a error). If you are exceeding `\maxdimen`  you could make a document half your desired size, with half size fonts, then scale up the final pdf on printing or via a pdf edit post process

Comment: `Is there a technical constraint for \maxdimen's value or way to configure to something higher?` that is 2^{30}sp and baked in to the syntax and implementation and can not be changed, even in luatex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the document at quarter size, then scale using `\mag` at the final size

pdfinfo confirms the page is 24in (1728bp) wide even though specified to `geometry` as `6in`

```
$ pdfinfo file.pdf 
...
Page size:      1728 x 2592 pts
```

[image]

```
\mag4000
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[papersize={6in,9in},margin=5pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}

\fontsize{1.2pt}{1.3pt}\selectfont
\begin{multicols}{15}

 \loop
  \ifnum\value{enumi}<1500
   \stepcounter{enumi}
   \roman{enumi}\par\Roman{enumi}\par\arabic{enumi}\par
   \roman{enumi}\par\Roman{enumi}\par\arabic{enumi}\par
  \repeat
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The TeX primitive `\setbo0=\vbox{...}` is able to construct the `\vbox` with arbitrary height. Then you can use TeX primitive `\vsplit0` in order to read a pieces of the accumulated material and set it into columns. No `\maxdimen` limit is reached when you are using these primitives.

I tried this with your document. I only replaced your `\begin{multicols}{13}` by  `\setbox0=\vbox\bgroup \hsize=3cm`, the `\end{multicols}` is replaced by `\egroup`. Then I added a material to your columns:

```
\count0=1
\loop 
   \the\count0 \par 
   \advance\count0 by1 
   \ifnum\count0<10000 \repeat
   % a real listing has >10k additional lines
```

Finally, I added the following routine after the `\endgroup`. It prints the accumulated material to columns:

```
\hbox{\count0=1
   \loop
      \vsplit0 to\vsize
      \advance\count0 by1
      \ifnum\count0<20 \repeat
}
```

No `\maxdimen` limit was reached, 20 very long columns were printed.

Comment: +1 I did wonder about trying this, but scaling seems safer, working with over-size boxes is so fragile , you can avoid the errors, but if you breath on it tex will calculate the `\ht` of the box for some reason and hit the error. But it is good to flag that the error happens when/if the size of a box is accessed not when the large box is generated.